# Proof of concept or proof-of-concept, noun or adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives

From the Oxford English Dictionary at [OED](http://www.oed.com/):

> **proof of concept** n. evidence (usually deriving from an experiment or pilot project) demonstrating that a design concept, business idea, etc., is feasible; a piece of such evidence; freq. attrib.
>
> *1994*  San Antonio Business Jrnl. (Nexis) 19 Aug. a4   "We built this center as a proof of concept."
>
> *2001*  Today's Pilot Feb. 51/1  "Although the GA-200 is a totally new aircraft, some heavily modified Pawnees were used as proof-of-concept aircraft."

So is it both a noun and an adjective?

I wrote in a document *"(...) successfully evaluated through a proof of concept prototype."* and now I'm wondering whether I should change it into *"(...) successfully evaluated through a proof of concept."*. I left the dashes out in both cases.

Comment: Normally there will be dashes when used attributively (≈ as an adjective) and no dashes when used as a noun phrase. Your suggested change makes no sense, though: how do you evaluate something through a piece of evidence? You can, I suppose, evaluate something through a prototype in the right context, but not through proof.

Comment: If it is hardware, I would think _successfully evaluated through a prototype we buildt as a proof of concept._

Comment: @mplungjan It's software. Following your suggestion, I changed it to *"A proof-of-concept prototype is implemented and successfully evaluated."*.

Comment: In that sentence you can skip the prototype - _A proof-of-concept has been implemented and successfully evaluated_ with or without dashes

Comment: @mplungjan No, as JBJ has already said "no dashes when used as a noun phrase".

Comment: Ok, then without but also without prototype

Comment: Like its related construct [_proof of purchase_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/proof-of-purchase), _proof of concept_ is unhyphenated. No reputable dictionary lists a hyphenated form. (I work for a company that's awash in both hardware and software proofs of concept, generically referred to as **PoC**.)

Answer (score 4):

Nouns are often used like adjectives. When used in this fashion, they are called *[noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)* or *attributive nouns*.

For example

> - chicken soup
> - horse barn
> - baseball diamond

*Proof of concept* is either a noun (when written with dashes) or a noun phrase, either of which can be used adjectivally.

Comment: Are these correct? *My proof-of-concept.* (noun), *My proof-of-concept implementation.* (noun as adjective: noun adjunct), and *My blue proof of concept.* (noun phrase with proof of concept as head noun).

Comment: The first two are fine. The last is grammatical, but makes no sense. But *my first proof of concept* would be fine.

Comment: I was trying to use blue as means of identification (=noun?) and not as an adjective. My reasoning is that it would result in noun + head noun. The prototypes are color coded instead of using numerals: blue, yellow, green and so on. I don't know if that would make more sense though.

Comment: Perhaps if fully laid out in context: *I have run three proof of concept experiments, code-named Red, Blue and Yellow.  The Blue proof of concept yielded the best results.* The grammar holds. But *blue* in this context is a straight-up adjective.

Comment: If we modify the sentence to *My Blue proof of concept.*, is it a valid assumption the writer means to identify a specific proof of concept? Notice the capital B.

Comment: Only if there is a previous reference to explain "Blue".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, It is correct to say

> My proof-of-concept implementation

since you can have a "proof-of-concept implementation" and a "final implementation"

it is wrong to say

> My proof-of-concept prototype

since you don't have "proof-of-concept prototype" and a "final prototype"

Unless your prototypes cost millions of dollars for each one.  e.g. aerospace.  Then you can have var. stages of the prototype itself.  Otherwise, the prototype is a *stage of* a bigger process

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you modify your sentence as follows:

Successfully evaluated by proof of principle (/studies).

As used here, I don't think you should include  'a' in the sentence because proof of concept/principle studies are not specific examples - they are generalizable demonstrations. In the same way that it is wrong to use the word prototype.

Otherwise I don't think there is a problem with it being used as a noun or as an adjective. And I think the hyphens are optional as the three words always go together.